# Message Brokers - Multiple consumers with this same client ID

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, messagebroker, apache-pulsar

I've been considering some multiple consumer problem with my system and unfortunately I'm really stuck. I mean - I see some solutions, which are below, but they are propably not enought efficient. Let me introduce system:

User has their specific Id. User can be logged on diffrent devices - many mobiles, many browsers in this same time. When user is offline every message which user has got should be provide when user is online. When user is online, should be kept informed on a regular basis about messages. Every user, when is online is connected by WebSocket.

So I have been thinking about message brokers from this pool - rabbitmq, kafka, apache pulsar ( All system above will be in Java ). And this is my thoughs about this:

1. Rabbitmq - Every device gets their own queue associated with client Id. But here i see some troubles. For example - user gonna log in 4 browsers and each will get new queue ( of course I assume that some not used queue will be deleted after time but this solution can be overloaded if somebody just wanna do this ).
2. One queue with marker for every user which messages were consumed - I tried implement this with apache Pulsar but my every attempt was running out with created new consumer (not continue as the same consumer) - Maybe I can't use this API?
3. Apache kafka - groups and partitions? Its similiar to point 1.

I will be really gratefull for every single hint - If You see some better solutions with other technology just let me know - I will adjust to this.

( If it matters - Java and SpringBoot are core of this )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can respond for the apache pulsar part - you need to set SubscriptionName in consumer to be equal to your UserId, this will ensure messages to be consumed starting from the last acknowledged one for that user.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer :)
I think, in this question I didn't describe my solution to the end - in particular with pulsar. This what I have been tried implement was a of course - as you mentioned some associate with userId and SubscriptionName. And in this post I didn't mention about situation when user has been logout and after time back - but in time when he was offline he got some data and currently he needs to process it.

Comment: My solution at this moment ( I will check it in a few days - how efficient it is ) is to remember last viewed message from pulsar and save into database. When user logs in again I will get this message from database and run reader from pulsar which will give me data from the last what user has seen to the newest. and after that i will be up to date

Comment: If you establish 1 to 1 association between UserId and SubscriptionName, you don't need to use external database and reader - only new messages will be delivered

Comment: yea - maybe I just can't use this API because I have been considering this option with pulsar as first. but every single time when I tried to create like this, my consumer was creating as new and he has reading "topic" from the beginning - not from the point where he was last time.
What i'm doing wrong? It's possible to retrieve this same consumer when I lost connection with pulsar?

Comment: If you use the same SubscriptionName, you'll get only new messages for that subscription. Subscription cursor is persisted on the server side

Comment: c1 = pulsarClient.newConsumer().topic("public/default/sk").subscriptionName("sub1s")
                .subscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Earliest)
                .subscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Exclusive)
                .subscribe();
I have been craeting in this style and every time I got new consumer :(.

Comment: Are you acknowledging message after consuming? Your setup is correct, so the only possible reason I think of is that you are not acknowledging messages

Comment: Oh, yea. You are right, I have missed it - daaaaamn... Thank You so much - for Your time and for Your involvement. Advantage of the opportunity:

Comment: 1. So its possible to kind of hide the websocket endpoints? It means - I have client ( browser )  who wants to consume same information from pulsar, but I want to hide direct link between browser and pulsar. I have been thinking about kind of proxy with Java - standard stomp over webSocket with sockJs ( simple message broker ) and try to listen pulsar from server side and when I got message i will hand over to the client via this simple message broker. Maybe exists better solution?

Comment: ( By the way in this particular scenario what You think about creating new listening thread which are associated with concrete websocket connection? )

2. It exists some more efficient solution to send message to many topics without creating for each a new producer? - Like in rabbitMQ I send message to all queues which are associated with some routing key?

Comment: 1. Pulsar supports many authorization schemes, check if they will work for you. You still might want to add java proxy to have more flexibility
2. In RabbitMQ topics are logical entity, in Pulsar they are physical entity, so you can't  easily send to all queues. So if selecting between Rabbit and Pulsar it's flexibility vs speed (Pulsar topics are similar to Kafka ones in this way)

Comment: Thank You again for your involvement. I think that, in this particular scenario better solution will be with flexibility - I mean, each time when I send data to the group ( every user has their specific topic ) i need to create producer, then send notification and close connection. Of course I can use kind of flyweight pattern to restrain of creating producer - but in this scenario one server will have many active connections with pulsar so it can be slowing down.  
After all  - Thank You for your answers :)